# Ajuda com uso de $_POST em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Olá, estou tendo o seguinte erro:

Notice: Undefined index: dataInicio in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\dashboard.php on line 124.

Aparentemente não estou fazendo o uso correto do $_POST, mas não sei onde estou errando, alguém pode me ajudar? Vou colocar o código para esclarecer como está sendo definido tudo:

Aqui no PHP eu pego o $_POST do index :

```
// Filtro data

$dataHumanaFim = "";
$dataHumanaInicio = "";

$dataHumanaInicio = $_POST['dataInicio'];
$dataHumanaFim = $_POST['dataFim'];

$sqlFiltroData = 'SELECT * from devices where first_time between "'.mktime($dataHumanaInicio).'" and "'.mktime($dataHumanaInicio).'"';
$filtroData = $pdo->query($sqlFiltroData);
//var_dump($filtroData);
```

Aqui é onde eu requisito os valores que deveriam ir para $_POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="dashboard.php">
  <div class="col-4">

  <label for="dataInicio">De:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dataInicio" name="dataInicio">
  <label for="dataFim">Até:</label>
  <input type="text" id="dataFim" name="dataFim">

</div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-alert" onclick="filtroData()" id="pesquisaFiltro" value="Pesquisa" name="submit">Pesquisar</button>
</form>
```

E aqui a função que faço no javascript/jquery para o botão... :

```
$(function filtroData(){
//Função para filtro por data
$('#pesquisaFiltro').click(function(){ 
document.getElementById("filtroData").removeAttribute("hidden");
});
});
```

Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando ou onde consigo verificar uma melhor maneira de fazer o que estou tentando?

Comment: $dataHumanaInicio = $_POST['dataInicio']; o erro na verdade acontece nessa linha e na linha 125:     $dataHumanaFim = $_POST['dataFim'];

Comment: Testei aqui e não deu erro: https://repl.it/@RonaldoVasques/InsistentUnequaledBytes . O erro deve estar em outra parte.

Comment: Outra coisa não se usa `onclick` com `submit`.

Comment: Acho que sei onde está o erro, estou fazendo tudo na mesma página, não separado como você mostra aí no exemplo de teste, talvez se eu jogar o PHP em outro arquivo e mudar o action para esse arquivo o erro suma... Vou testar

Comment: Bom, alterei o action para "envia.php" e coloquei as variaveis lá bem como está no seu exemplo, e o erro segue o mesmo, só mudou o local... : Notice: Undefined index: dataInicio in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\envia.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: dataFim in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\envia.php on line 8

Comment: É muito grande o código? Se não for, manda um repl.it com o seu código para ser analisado.

Comment: É meio grande sim, acho que não dá para reproduzir tudo no repl.it ... Tem algum outro meio ?

Comment: Github, mas eu trabalho. Eu gasto os intervalos do café aqui no StackOverflow. Se for muito grande assim eu não vou ter como conciliar as coisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que entendi, você colocou no mesmo arquivo, então se você não envia o POST ele busca o index e não acha.

E como você está abrindo a página para mostrar o form, o php tenta buscar o index no array post e não encontra.

Smpre use o isset() para verificar se e var está setada:

```
if(isset($_POST['dataInicio']) && isset($_POST['dataFim'])) {
    $dataHumanaInicio = $_POST['dataInicio'];
    $dataHumanaFim = $_POST['dataFim'];
}
```

Desta forma o php vai ver que as variaveis não existem ainda e segue o jogo.

Resumindo, se você enviar o form ele vai funcionar da forma que está, o problema é que você não consegue abrir a página para enviar o form.

Colocando o cód acima vai funcionar.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo, era exatamente isto que faltava. Muito obrigado pela explicação, ficou bem claro, eu não entendia direito o funcionamento do isset e você esclareceu. Muito bom!!!